# How to get just the root element from Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have the following XElement:

```
 <Assembly name="3">
  <Component name="2" /> 
 </Assembly>
```

I would like to get just the root element.  `<Assembly name="3">` I cant see any method which suits for me.

```
  XElement.????? I cant find XElement.Root;
```

Does any clue?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [`RemoveNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.removenodes.aspx) on it... create a copy first if you need to preserve the original content for other reasons.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do with this. The element logically contains all its children - there's no concept of `XElement.Root` because an element "is itself". `RemoveNodes` will remove all the child nodes, but if you just want to get the name of the element, or its attributes, you can do that without changing the structure at all.

Comment: I found out this Xelement in a Linq-Query. Then I need to insert another Xelement into this one-... edit. wow i can insert another XElement Without extract the Root.

I found the answer. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @kmxillo: So just call `element.Add(extraElement)`. Why do you need to strip it first? Adding context to your question would help a lot.

Comment: Old question, but I have to add this, as the answer is misleading. In any typical tree, there's always a root, and for XML in particular, it is very well defined. It is the last of the transitive closure of `Parent`, or the last of the ancestors in reverse document order. Since most trees are rooted at a document node, from any node you can simply use `someNode.Document.Root` (the last bit `Root` gives you the root element). If you have parentless nodes, you will need to get the first from `someNode.Ancestors()`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this in VB.NET

```
Dim elm as XElment = XElement.Parse(<Assembly name="3">
                                     <Component name="2" /> 
                                    </Assembly>)

Dim strName as string 
strName = elm.AncestorsAndSelf.First.Name
```

Code in C#

```
XElement elm = XElement.Parse("<Assembly name='3'><Component name='2' /></Assembly>");
string name =elm.AncestorsAndSelf().First().Name;
```

Comment: This is better than the other answers, because it doesn't presume that the `XElement` is rooted in a document node. This will always get the top-most ancestor element.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the root element this way :

```
XDocument.Root
```

Here is an example of implementation :

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
new XComment("This is a comment."),
new XElement("Pubs", 
    new XElement("Book",
        new XElement("Title", "Artifacts of Roman Civilization"),
        new XElement("Author", "Moreno, Jordao")
    ),
    new XElement("Book",
        new XElement("Title", "Midieval Tools and Implements"),
        new XElement("Author", "Gazit, Inbar")
    )
),
new XComment("This is another comment.")
);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Name.ToString());
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx

Comment: Skeet´s answer is easier to implement. Thanks

Comment: This answer may look more complex than the accepted answer (which changes the tree!), but that's only because it shows how to create a tree as well. The part that matters is `doc.Root`.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the name & attributes to a new element;

```
var root = new XElement(el.Name, el.Attributes());
```